# Ameritrade API Streaming Futures - Symbol Naming Conventions?

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net

**This question is for anyone who has successfully coded the TD Ameritrade API streamer**

My apologies for the very narrow scope of this question - you either know the answer or you don't. I've tried literally everything I can think of and nothing and it's near crunch-time.

If you have used the Ameritrade API for streaming real-time quotes - **do you know the conventions used for futures?** These are the "slash" items in ThinkOrSwim (/CL(WTI) /M6E(Euro/$) /YG(Gold) etc.). Only they don't translate to the streaming subscriptions (likely due to the need for a frontslash). As with some other stocks, I'll bet Ameritrade is using a different naming convention for streamers than they do for ThinkOrSwim.

```
 string[] indices = new string[] { "$DJI", "SPX.X", "$COMPX" };//Indices
 string[] tick = new string[] { "$TICK", "$TIKI", "$TIKSP", "$TIKRL" };//TICK
 string[] vix = new string[] { "TVIX", "XIV" };//regular symbols
 string[] futures = new string[] {"/CL","/YG","/M6E","/SL"};//These DON'T work! That's what I need! How do they transfer to the API?
```

*The API docs clearly mention that futures are part of the streaming response, but offer no conventions*. Ameritrade's API department has been non-responsive for the last few months.

**PS** I've tried pretty near everything, including removing the slash, escaping/encoding it, using the "long" CBOE names -- there's no point in guessing here unless you've actually done it.

I've tried everything I can think of, including the "actual" CBOE symbols, but get BAD REQUEST error.

Having access to the futures is paramount to my algo. I would be **MUCH** obliged if you'd be kind enough to share your knowledge if you have it. Thanks for your time and thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

PS- My logic in tagging this ?? is that the old SDK was written in C++ with ports to .NET - so those languages would have the highest degree of likelihood of reaching someone with experience in the API. Not trying to tag-spam.

**EDIT** There is some information out there available on Google that futures are not part of the API. This information was from before they updated their API to include many other things. I am basing the probablility that futures  do exist now because options were not availablbe before (they are now), and futures are now available through a different type of streamer (where they weren't before). It makes no sense to me that TDA would upgrade 80% of their stuff but not the last 20%. Also, from the API documentation:

> 52.7 Level I
>   Level 1 provide Equity, Option and Futures quotes and trades data.
>   52.7.1 Level I Equities
>   The QUOTE server ID is used to request Level I quotes on stocks, indices, futures, and mutual funds. For options, you would use the OPTION Service ID

So that leads me to believe that futures ARE available - I just don't know how to name them.

Thanks!

Comment: Just googled a bit and found some forum posts indicating futures are not part of the deal.

Comment: Hey Plutonix. Thanks for the effort. Unfortunately, I believe that information to be old. They updated their systems after those posts were made to include options and mutual funds (those work fine). Then, the API documentation specifically references futures, as well. The fact that they updated makes sense as to why that information is out there. So this is either a typo or they upgraded to include options & mutual funds but skipped futures. Also, they changed the names of some symbols with non-AN characters, which leads me to think that's what they've done with to handle the "/" character.

Comment: You are probably right, but one in particular I recall had a post from 2016 asking if that was still the case with an answer in the affirmative.  Could still be outdated though.

Comment: What I meant to say was there is either a typo in the API docs or I'm missing something. I really appreciate your work on this, though. Thank you!

Comment: If the bas%$ds would just answer their emails. They tout this great API system and it takes three months for them to respond with an auth token and they absolutely won't respond to this.

Comment: The sub par support was also mentioned.  You might poke around tools that interact with the API and see if you can either glean some info or ask directly.

Comment: I also have attempted to contact them with some basic questions, and never heard back, so I feel your pain on the support side. Normally in that situation I would recommend cracking open the DLL and peeking at the code yourself. That doesnt help much, seeing as how there is no way to inspect code yourself with cloud APIs anymore....

Comment: Thanks - and exactly - the API is all on my end via streaming HTTP (send request, get binary, translate), so there's no clue as to how the server processes things or what it's looking for. I really appreciate your efforts!

Comment: can the slash-symbols be escaped for however they are submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your question, I've decided to register at TD Ameritrade. Take note of what is on their register page:

[image: Futures data not yet available]

This screenshot was made at 2016-10-04 at 10:28 GMT time. Sorry if this response disappoints you. Also take not on part which says that threads relating to the futures data have been blocked and hidden.

Comment: Thank you, Zura! I'll bet you $20 they did that because of me lol. I've written them probably 100 times over the last three months - I puled my registration and it wasn't on it. You da man! Not good news - but news. And I thank you for it. If you want some code that puts the basic framework in place for account actions, trades, streaming, etc - let me know by PM

Comment: If I'll ever work with Ameritrade, I'll definitely contact you. Thanks for proposal

Comment: COMMON Ameritrade! It's already 2021 and STILL no access to historical futures data.

Answer (score 3):

I have no issue streaming futures data.

You can see on their streaming API page here:
https://developer.tdameritrade.com/content/streaming-data

that in the example /ES is used. I've tried /CL and /RTY as well.

You can also get real time quotes for futures using the quotes end point:
https://developer.tdameritrade.com/quotes/apis

What is not supported for futures is historical data (price history end point) and tragically the most important thing: trading futures. It truly is a pity given that their API is actually very good for equity and options trading. I like TDA's API better than IB's because it's web-based (RESTful) and you don't have to worry about running their platform in the background the way you have to do with IB.

There is this person making lots of great codes and youtube videos around TDA's new API. His channel name is Sigmacoding. Highly recommended content.

Answer (score 2):

If you're streaming to Level One Quotes, then here are the symbols you'll need for the different "instruments".

1. Equities - `"SPY"`
2. Futures - `"/ES"`
3. Options - `"AAPL_040920C115"`
4. Forex - `"EUR/USD"`
5. Futures Options `"./EW2J20C2675"`

Comment: This helps, but isn't the complete picture.  Eg ES as of writing this is /ESU0 but the api does not seem to like that format.

Comment: I believe that they only provide "Continuous" prices for historical data, with pricing blurred into the active contract. (which makes it pretty useless for back-testing, very unfortunate)

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same boat. I am interested in getting data for forex futures. Ex: EURUSD.
There really is no documentation. I cant use the API but am able to use TD streaming data to get what I need (trust me it was pain. me being a novice python developer)
anyway, following nomenclature helped me.

```
TD Ameritrade EURO FX symbols
FUTURE Symbol:
    /6E+QUARTER MONTH+YEAR 
    ex: /6EH19 = H for march quarter, 19 year 2019
    ex: /6EM20 = H for June quarter, 20 year 2020

FUTURE_OPTION_SYMBOL:
    /EUU+MONTH+YEAR
    ex: /EUUJ20 for /66EM20 means: J for April option with expiration
```

Below are symbols that TD streaming accepts:

```
-------------------------------
"service": "LEVELONE_FUTURES"
"keys": "/6EM21"
-------------------------------
-------------------------------
"service": "LEVELONE_FUTURES_OPTIONS"
"keys": "./EUUJ22C1.175"
-------------------------------
-------------------------------
"service": "LEVELONE_FOREX"
"keys": "EUR/USD"
-------------------------------
```

Below is an excerpt from a website (cant remember which one)

```
**Futures Symbols**
Futures and Futures Options can be obtained from the following exchanges: CME, CBOT, COMEX, KCBT, MGEX, ICE, NYMEX, and others. Trade the Currencies, Energies, Financials, Grains, Indices, Meats, Metals, and Softs. Press CTRL-F on the keyboard to search down through the symbols
Futures Commodity symbols are created in three parts:
the root symbol, the month code, and the year code.

The month code is represented with a single letter as displayed below:

    F - January
    G - February
    H - March (accepted by TD)
    J - April
    K - May
    M - June (accepted by TD)
    N - July
    Q - August
    U - September (accepted by TD)
    V - October
    X - November
    Z - December (accepted by TD)
    
    The year code is displayed as one digit:
    2018 would be displayed as 8
    2019 would be displayed as 9
    
    For example, the E-mini S&P 500, December 2018 would be -ESZ8
    -ES is the root symbol
    Z is the month of December
    8 is for the year 2018
    
    Sample Futures Symbols
    -ESZ8     E-mini S&P 500, December 2018 contract
    -NQH9 nbsp;    E-mini Nasdaq, March 2019 contract
    -YMH9     E-mini Dow Jones, March 2019 contract
```

Comment: I think you're correct.  According to https://developer.tdameritrade.com/content/streaming-data#_Toc504640603, "Futures symbol as a product or active symbol (ie. /ES or /ESM4)".  I just doesn't specify which characters to use for the month, so I'm going to assume your format is correct.

Comment: I just confirmed it with my code.  The quote from TD is incorrect.  It should be like your example using the 2-digit year.  So, it should really read, "Futures symbol as a product or active symbol (ie. /ES or /ESM14)", which would be, for /ESM14, the ES futures for the June 2014 contract.

Answer (score 1):

TDAmeritrade's new API is build internally.  The old API was farmed out to a set of brother who would respond in great detail. Their old forum is dead !!  The old API will be eventually taken down. The new API has the rule that they will NOT provide any Technical help, they only answer for clarification of there documented API.  And of course what you need is buried in https://developer.tdameritrade.com/content/streaming-data